# Conversion tracking not working

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I want to track conversions in my wordpress page. Google analytics has worked so far without any problems.

For us a conversion is if a visitor visits the page http://www.mypage.com/thanks/ ...

Therefore I've setup a goal in Google Analytics (default template) with target to /thanks/.
I tried goal type "Equals to" and "Regular expression":
[image: Google Analytics]

According Google Analytics there have been no conversions so far.
But according to the content report the page http://www.mypage.com/thanks/ was visited 16 times today ...

Comment: Look later today or tomorrow. Google's conversion stats aren't real-time.

Comment: Click the "verify"-Link to see if it reports a conversion rate larger than 0 (that one works with realtime data).

Comment: Verify says there are no conversions.
Ok, I'll check later again.

Comment: If verify says there are not conversions then your goal is not set up correctly - that's the point of verifying goals, to see if they work or not.

Comment: It is working now. You were right. It's not realtime. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now.
It just needed some time (see comment of Eike Pierstorff (thank you!)).